# Flutter, when cleaning list that already got added to list, the values are gone

Tags: flutter

I need to sort the elements by their data.
For example:

When I have 4 entries and 2 of them have the same date, the result will be 3 entries in the result list

This is my code:

```
  Future<List<List<MoodData>>> moodData() async {
    var result = await database
        .ref()
        .child("users/")
        .child(user!.uid)
        .child("moodData")
        .once();
    List<MoodData> x = [];
    List<List<MoodData>> resultdata = [];

    result.snapshot.children.forEach((element) {
      maxID = int.parse(element.key.toString());
      print(element.child("date").value);
      if (x.length != 2) {
        x.add(MoodData(
            id: int.parse(element.key.toString()),
            date: element.child("date").value.toString(),
            moodValue: double.parse(element.child("y_value").value.toString()),
            text: element.child("text").value.toString()));
      } else {
        resultdata.add(x);
        x.clear();
      }
    });
    print(resultdata);
    return resultdata;
  }
```

The problem is, that in the result list, all the elemts are empty lists.

What is my code doing wrong?

Comment: Dart does not implicitly copy objects.  When you do `resultdata.add(x)`, `resultdata` gets a copy of the *reference* to the same `List` object that `x` refers to.  If you want a copy, you must create one explicitly: `resultdata.add(x.toList())` or `resultdata.add([...x])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you adding `x` to `resultdata` it **not produces the copy** of `x`, `x` just becomes an element of `resultdata`.
Then you have 2 options for accessing `x` data:

- Using given name `x`
- Get it from `resultdata` by index

So when you call `x.clear()` after `resultdata.add(x)` it's the **same** as calling `resultdata.last.clear()`.

The right **solution** is adding a copy of `x`(`[...x]`) to `resultdata`:

```
resultdata.add([...x]);
x.clear();
```